# Sending multiple messages with twilio

Tags: api, notifications, twilio, whatsapp

I have tried to send WhatsApp messages by twilio as notifications.
Does WhatsApp or Twilio have a limit amount of messages sent per second?
Is there any problem or additional cost if I send URL's in those messages?
I have a whatsapp business account.

Comment: I'd say it's very likely they have the limits set up to prevent spamming

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio currently supports sending up to 25 messages per second through WhatsApp.](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/support-25-mps-whatsapp) If messages are sent at a rate higher than 25 MPS, Twilio maintains a queue. For very high outbound message volumes, messages can remain queued for up to 4 hours.

To achieve higher MPS, you can use Messaging Services. This allows you to distribute high volume across many WhatsApp senderes within the Messaging Service.